# A simple screen video capturing application with well compressed output

Tags: software-rec, screen-capture

I am looking for very simple screen capturing application that outputs well compressed files. I does not need to be able to capture audio, video will suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you already have the free media player VLC? If so you can just open it up and hit ctrl+n then type in "screen://". This will let you record the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

As luck would have it I'm currently writing a post for the [SuperUser Blog](http://blog.superuser.com/). You may find some answers in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/6801/what-is-the-best-software-for-desktop-recording), or alternatively, try [Jing](http://www.techsmith.com/jing/).

Answer (score 0):

[CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/) is a good free choice. Output compression is configurable to taste or need.

Comment: Yeah, for simple screen recording, Camstudio is a good choice. You can install H.264 or xvid codec for best compression.